# How to translate, scale, and rotate an image around an origin point

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm building an image editing tool, which currently translates, scales, and rotates an image that can be dragged around the canvas. I'm using the [DOMMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix/DOMMatrix) API to apply a transform to a canvas. This works (see working example below), but only around the centre point of the image.

How can I apply the rotation to any origin point of the canvas, e.g. (0.5, 0.5) would be the centre, (0.0, 0.1) would be the bottom left, etc.?

I currently have the translation applied to the image, so that is can rotate around the image given an origin point. I need to have it so that when the image is large and slightly off-canvas, the user can see the centre canvas is what the origin point is, and the image rotates around that.

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-cherry-i1ts0p?file=/src/index.js) demo that demonstrates rotating around the canvas centre point, but causes the drag padding with the pointer to be misaligned.

#### Demo

**[Editable CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hertz-o5eh0g?file=/src/index.js)**

Shortcut keys:

- "r" rotates by 5°
- "-" zooms out 0.1
- "=" zooms in -0.1

```js
let rotation = 0;
let scale = 1;
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let startX = 0;
let startY = 0;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;
let pointerDown = false;

const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const imgWidth = 480;
const imgHeight = 300;

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

resizeCanvas();
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);

const img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/3q3kNGh.png";

function onPointerDown(event) {
  pointerDown = true;
  startX = (event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft) / imgWidth;
  startY = (event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop) / imgHeight;
}

function onPointerMove(event) {
  if (!pointerDown) return;
  x = lastX + ((event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft) / imgWidth - startX);
  y = lastY + ((event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop) / imgHeight - startY);
}

function onPointerUp() {
  pointerDown = false;
  lastX = x;
  lastY = y;
}

window.addEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown);
window.addEventListener("pointermove", onPointerMove);
window.addEventListener("pointerup", onPointerUp);

window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  const key = event.key.toLowerCase();
  switch (key) {
    case "r":
      rotation = (rotation + 5) % 360;
      break;
    case "-":
      scale = Math.max(0, scale - 0.1);
      break;
    case "=":
      scale = Math.min(2, scale + 0.1);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});

function rotate(x, y, rotation) {
  const panXX = x * Math.cos((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panXY = y * Math.sin((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panYY = y * Math.cos((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panYX = x * Math.sin((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);
  const panX = panXX + panXY;
  const panY = panYY - panYX;
  return { x: panX, y: panY };
}

(function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  const imgX = imgWidth * x;
  const imgY = imgHeight * y;

  const { x: tX, y: tY } = rotate(imgX, imgY, rotation);

  const matrix = new DOMMatrix()
    .translate(imgWidth / 2, imgHeight / 2)
    .rotate(rotation)
    .translate(imgWidth / -2, imgHeight / -2)
    .translate(tX, tY)
    .scale(scale);

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.setTransform(matrix);

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);

  ctx.resetTransform();
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already playing with the rotation origin... Just before the rotate, you translate one way then translate the other way:

```
.translate(imgWidth / 2, imgHeight / 2)
.rotate(rotation)
.translate(imgWidth / -2, imgHeight / -2)
```

If you change those parts to translate accordingly you could achieve just what you want. Without translation (0,0) you'd have the origin at top left corner. For top right you'd translate by imgWidth,0 and then -imgWidth,0

You'll simply need to set some variable to know which point you want and use it.

EDIT: as per requested after, OP wanted to have the rotation be relative to the canvas and not the image, so the translate should use the canvas dimension instead. Also there was a problem in translating when the image was rotated, this is fixed by applying the rotation to the translation, as per OP's code:

```
  const imgX = imgWidth * x;
  const imgY = imgHeight * y;

  const { x: tX, y: tY } = rotate(imgX, imgY, rotation);

  const ox = canvas.width / 2 - x;
  const oy = canvas.height / 2 - imgY;

  const matrix = new DOMMatrix()
    .translate(ox, oy)
    .rotate(rotation)
    .translate(ox * -1, oy * -1)
    .translate(tX, tY)
    .scale(scale);
```

Comment: Apologies, I think my original question was mis-worded, I meant "origin point of the canvas", not "origin point of the image". I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: Wouldn't simply using the canvas sizes instead of the image's size work??

Comment: Yes, it does, but the problem is it messes up the drag functionality. See here for an updated CSB link that demonstrates this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-cherry-i1ts0p?file=/src/index.js

Comment: If you use your rotated x and y it works fine. `const ox = canvas.width / 2 - x;`

Comment: Oh, yes you are right, thank you!. Here is the solved CSB link: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-frog-zxqcdh?file=/src/index.js

Can you update your answer and I'll mark it as solved?

Comment: Also, instead of creating a new matrix everytime, you may want to use a permanent matrix... Instead of applying absolute transforms, you could apply multiple consecutive transformations.

Like instead of translating by the image by just one value, you'd translate the matrix everytime the user translates. Then do the rotation, then retranslate etc. A matrix is made so you can apply multiple transformations to it easily, use that power.